# Joining tables with LIKE (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

First of all I am using Oracle:

Table One Name = `tableone`

Table Two Name = `tabletwo`

`tableone` has a column named `pizzaone`, `tabletwo` has a column named `pizzatwo`.  I want to join `tableone` to `tabletwo` where `pizzaone` is somewhere in the `pizzatwo`'s name.

What I tried:

```
select * 
from tableone 
   join tabletwo on tableone.pizzaone like ('%' + tabletwo.pizzatwo + '%')
```

How can I correct this query?

Comment: Correct in what way? Did you get an error message, or is there a performance issue, something like that?

Comment: ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Might be an idea to state what SQL engine you are using.  Oracle from the last error code I assume.

Comment: ORA error means an Oracle database.

Comment: Can you post your two table definitions?

Comment: No Charles I cant sorry.  But both columns are VARCHAR2(40 BYTE) any thing else in specific you need to know?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this syntax instead:

```
select * 
from tableone 
   join tabletwo on tableone.pizzaone like ('%' || tabletwo.pizzatwo || '%')
```

Oracle's string concatenation operator is the double pipe (||). The invalid number error is because Oracle expects numeric operands for the '+' operator.

Comment: The double pipe is ANSI as well for SQL string concatenation.