# “ORA-01722: invalid number” error even if there are no numbers involved in the query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following query

```
SELECT T1.col2
FROM T1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 
  ON ',' + T2.col2 + ','  LIKE '%,' + T1.col1 + ',%'
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fdc043/6)

There are no numbers involved in it. Still it is showing following error

> ORA-01722: invalid number : SELECT T1.col2 FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON ',' + T2.col2 + ',' LIKE '%,' + T1.col1 + ',%'

How can we fix it?

**REFERENCES**

1. [Oracle faq - ORA-01722](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01722)

Comment: Use "||" to concatenate strings, not "+"...

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy Thanks - I was just trying with SQL Server syntax.. Good learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am new to Oracle and it was an incorrect syntax. We need to use `||` instead of `+`. The concatenation operator is different than SQL Server

1. [Concatenation Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/operators003.htm)
2. [Joining tables with LIKE (SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224907/joining-tables-with-like-sql)

However, the message `ORA-01722: invalid number` seems to be misleading

Comment: The `invalid number` error comes from the fact that you were using the operator to add *numbers*. Therefor Oracle tried to convert the all involved arguments into numbers but failed doing that for apparent reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The + operator expects numbers as it's operands. If you give it strings then they are invalid numbers. So it is technically correct, the best kind of correct.

Welcome to Oracle. :D